Laravel + MySQL + AWS - Loadtesting 1,000 concurrent bots performance issues
When running a load test with 1000 bots on our quiz application platform, we ran into some performance issues.
The load test we did previously was with 500 bots and the average response time was 0.333s. Everything went smoothly and nothing alarming in AWS (Perfect!)
However, when testing with a 1,000 bots the average response time went to 2.61s… (Not perfect!)
When looking at AWS, I can't see any issues or limitations. In fact, AWS Aurora only spiked to 10% CPU during the test.
In the monitoring tool, Sentry.io, we had an alert saying one of the SQL queries was running slow with a response time of 785.25ms.. The query in question is responsible for getting the quiz data from the database via the slug parameter. This is a very performant query with proper indexes setup and shouldn’t take this long.
db.sql.query - select *
from `quizzes`
where `slug` = ?
limit 1

This makes me think there is something in AWS causing this.. possibly due to cold starts or a DB/Lambda connection quota limitations? However, looking through the dashboards and insights I can't see anything which confirms this.
The only thing I can see is during the test the wait/io/table/sql/handler wait event spiked the total DB load to 120 (see below).. But we were still only using 2 CPUs at this point and still below our max of 6 ACUs (12 GiB) so shouldn’t be a bottleneck.





Can any one suggest how to improve the performance in this case?
Here is the load test script:
const urlApiBase = 'https://xxxxxx.com/api/v1/';
const roundId = bot.getVariable('RoundId');
const quizId = bot.getVariable('QuizId');

// 0. Capture round and quiz id
https://urlApiBase + /v1/quiz/IxqyIDNN-loadster-test-quiz-24th-april-2024

 // 1, Participate in quiz
const participantName = bot.getVariable('participant', 0);

http.post(urlApiBase + 'quiz/' + quizId + '/participate', 
    {
        name: participantName + '_' + new Date().toISOString()
    },
        {
     validators: [
        response => {
                var body = response.json();
                bot.setVariable('ParticipantId', body.participant_id);
                return true;
            }
        ]
    }
)


const participantId = bot.getVariable('ParticipantId');

// 2. Participate in quiz round
http.post(urlApiBase + 'quiz/' + quizId + '/participate/' + participantId + '/round/' + roundId, {}, {
     validators: [
        response => {
            var body = response.json();
            if (!body.round_id) {
                console.error('Cannot participate in round. Exiting early.')
                bot.exit();
            } 
           return true;
        }
    ]
});
        
// 2. Play quiz round
let hasCompleted = false;
let questionId = null;
let answerId = null;
    
// Get first question
http.get(
    urlApiBase + 'quiz/' + quizId + '/round/' + roundId + '/participant/' + participantId + '/question', 
    {
     validators: [
        response => {
            var body = response.json();
        
            if (body.question) {
                   let answers = body.question.answers; 
                   questionId = body.question.id;
                   answerId = answers[answers.length * Math.random() | 0].id;
            } else {
                hasCompleted = true;
            }
            return true;
        }
     ]
    }
);

bot.wait(getWaitTime());

while (!hasCompleted) {
    http.post(
        urlApiBase + 'quiz/' + quizId + '/round/' + roundId + '/participant/' + participantId + '/answer', 
        {
          answer_id: answerId,
          question_id: questionId
        },
        {
         validators: [
            response => {
                var body = response.json();
                if (body.next_question.length == 0) {
                   hasCompleted = true;
                } else {
                    let answers = body.next_question.question.answers; 
                    questionId = body.next_question.question.id;
                    answerId = answers[answers.length * Math.random() | 0].id;
                }
                return true;
            }
        ]
        }
    );
    
    bot.wait(getWaitTime());
}

bot.exit();

function getWaitTime() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1) * 1000
}



wait/io/table/sql/handler seems to relate to database disk IO (so wouldn't cause a CPU or memory use spike). I don't really know how  to properly configure the database storage in AWS so I would just recommend an in-memory cache for this query if indeed this is a bottleneck query

MySQL is not designed to have 1000 simultaneous connections.  It is, on the other hand, designed to handle that many if they are spread out over some small amount of time.
The server gives each connection an equal chance to proceed.  This leads to leads to a bottleneck.  (Imagine 1000 shoppers in a store at once.)
I recommend setting max_connection = 500 (or less) and back_log to the rest.
Also, let's see if the queries can be sped up.  Is there an index on slug?  (Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE quizzes; and the cardinality of slug.  If slug is not indexed, then 1000 simultaneous table scans is quite a burden.  If the cardinality is low, the index may be shunned.
LIMIT without ORDER BY is somewhat meaningless. The row you get should be assumed to be unpredictable. If the benchmark does not care which row, then I will quibble with the benchmark's applicability.

Thanks Rick - even though I'm testing with 1,000 bots.. There is a natural wait time between requests to the database. I've attached the load test script to my original question above. As you can see, i'm calculating a random wait time of 1-4 seconds between each request. The load test also is set to ramp up aggressively for 1 minute. Yes - there is an index setup on the slug column (see explain query above)

The "ramp-up" sounds like it would take hour(s) to execute 1000 queries.  What am I missing?  What is the value of Max_used_connections after the test?
